# What kind of file formats supports the torque marker-file?

Tags: carto, markers, torque, animatedmarker

I want my marker-file to be a gif 'cause I want to have a moving footsteps effect.

I've tried but it doesn't work well, it shows like the gif is an static image.

> tami_3[value=1]{marker-file: url(https://thumbs.gfycat.com/GratefulPlainBactrian-size_restricted.gif);
>   }

When I try with other gifs, they move, but they are really small.
Someone with the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

The CartoCSS property marker-file only accepts image format files like png ,jpg or svg. In [this section](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/cartocss/properties/#marker-file-uri) of the CARTO documentation you can find detailed information about the marker-file property.

On the other hand, in [this section](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/cartocss/properties-for-torque/) of the CARTO documentation you can find detailed information about the CartoCSS styles for Torque maps.